# Difficulty Accessing PHP Files in Vercel Deployment

Tags: php, html, css, github, vercel

I'm encountering an issue with my Vercel deployment, specifically related to accessing PHP files. I'm currently in the process of deploying my PHP project on Vercel, and while it's not perfect yet, my immediate goal is to make it work and access other PHP files.Currently, when attempting to access pages for example login.php, the same index.php page is displayed, but with a the login.php URL. Additionally, the logo (logo.png) is not loading on the pages. Here's a snapshot of my project structure:

```
/pravaliacumobila
|-- login.php
|-- logout.php
|-- logo.png
|-- style.css
|-- mobila dormitor.php
|-- ... (other PHP files)
------
/api
|-- index.php
------
|-- vercel.json
```

here is the vercel.json file:

```
{
  "functions": {
    "api/**/*.php": {
      "runtime": "vercel-php@0.6.1"
    }
  },
  "routes": [
    { "src": "/(.*)",  "dest": "/api/index.php" },
    { "src": "/pravaliacumobila/logo.png", "dest": "/pravaliacumobila/logo.png" },
    { "src": "/pravaliacumobila/signup.php", "dest": "/pravaliacumobila/signup.php" },
    { "src": "/pravaliacumobila/style.css", "dest": "/pravaliacumobila/style.css" },
    //...[the rest sources]
  ]
}
```

I've experimented with different project structures, including moving PHP files to an api folder based on recommendations, but the issue persists.